# How does the following corollary 3 follow from corollary 2 in I.N Herstein?

Tags: group-theory, totient-function

In I.N Herstein's Topics in Algebra is given certain corollaries which follow from a definition.

Quoting:

> COROLLARY 2 $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $If G is a finite group and $a \in G$, then $a^{o(G)}=e$

This is clear to me.

The book then goes on to talk about how for an integer $n$, numbers less than $n$ and relatively prime to
$n$ form a group under *multiplication mod* $n$ with order $\phi(n)$

Firstly. I do not understand what is meant by "multiplication mod n" and

Secondly, how corollary 3 (given below) follows from corollary 2 using the above group.

> COROLLARY 3$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $If n is a positive integer and a is relatively prime to $n$, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\ mod \  n$

Now, the Left-hand side in corollary 3 is the same as that of corollary 2 since for the group in which $a$ belongs the order is $\phi(n)$ as mentioned above.

This then means that the RHS in corollary should be identity.

So, I think my issue lies with the meaning of "multiplication mod n" and how for this binary operation 1 mod n is identity.

Comment: The integers form a ring. For a given $n>0$, the multiples of $n$ form an ideal in this ring. "multiplication mod $n$" means multiplication in the quotient ring, the quotient of the integers by the ideal.

Comment: A more lowbrow explanation is, multiply two integers as per normal, then replace the result by the remainder you get when you divide by $n$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson "multiply two integers as per normal, then replace the result by the remainder you get when you divide by n." so that $ab=r\ mod\ n$?  where r=remainder

Comment: Yes, where $r$ is the remainder when you divide $ab$ by $n$.